# 8051 with Keil-C filesize issue using a Megawin processor

Tags: 8051

I've written a program using Keil C for a MegaWin 8051 MPC82G516A. When I check the file size of the Intel generated hex file it has a size of 8kb (I see the code in the binary code window), but when I go to program the device using Megawin's tool it increases the code size to around 29kb!? Can anyone provide the reason for why it might be doing this?

Also, something else that is strange is the fact that it seems to be writing the code at the top of the processor memory and not at the start. There are like 4 bytes at the start of the code, but the complete rest of it is in the end of the memory.

Please help

Cameron.

Comment: maybe you should also ask here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you. I have done this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was miss-reading the file size on the editor. Also, Keil's free version starts at position 2000Kb. It's part of it's limitations of the evaluation version.

Answer (score 0):

you write that the file size of the intel hex file with your code is about 8k. Part of your program is written to the bottom of the address space.
Another part is written to the bottom of the address space.

The intel hex file not only contains the program code but also the address where that code should be written to. 
You can check yourself if your file contains code for the bottom and the top of the address space.
Some information about intel hex format: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/oh166/oh166_ih_record.htm

If this is the case you can check the .m51 file which is generated by the linker during the build process.
This file contains information about the modules included in your programm and the addresses they are linked to.
Perhaps there is some linker setting in your project which tells the linker behave as you tell.